# Which event is get emmited by gridjs after search completion

Tags: gridjs, gridjs-react

I am trying to use the event from gridjs. but as I was only able to access the
ready, load, and beforeload event.but for search event completion.
or other events where can I find the documentation for gridjs

Which event is get emmited by gridjs after search completion.

I tried to use following

grid.on('ready', ()=>{})

ready, beforeLoad, load, these events are working in react but for search event completion.
or row edit event.

how can I access these events.